# XInclude and Scales XML

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing, xinclude, scales-xml

I'm using the [Scales library](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) to process XML in Scala, and I'd like to have [`xi:include` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) expanded during parsing. This doesn't happen by default—if I write the following, for example, any `include` elements in the XML file will appear unexpanded in the parsed document:

```
import java.io.FileReader
import scales.utils._, ScalesUtils._
import scales.xml._, ScalesXml._

val doc = loadXml(new FileReader("data/example.xml"))
```

Is it possible to have these elements expanded? I'm using Scales 0.6.0-M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It's at least possible. You can write your own `SAXParserFactory` pool on the model of the provided [`DefaultSAXParserFactoryPool`](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml/blob/ab46f5877323e1842d09292dd756e3973f5323aa/core/src/main/scala/scales/xml/impl/XmlFactories.scala#L55):

```
import javax.xml.parsers.{ SAXParser, SAXParserFactory }
import scales.utils._, ScalesUtils._
import scales.xml._, ScalesXml._
import scales.xml.parser.sax.DefaultSaxSupport

object XIncludeSAXParserFactoryPool extends
  resources.SimpleUnboundedPool[SAXParserFactory] { pool =>

  def create = {
    val parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
    parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)
    parserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true)
    parserFactory.setXIncludeAware(true)
    parserFactory.setValidating(false)
    parserFactory
  }

  val parsers = new resources.Loaner[SAXParser] with DefaultSaxSupport {
    def loan[X](tThunk: SAXParser => X): X =
      pool.loan(x => tThunk(x.newSAXParser))
  }
}
```

Then you can specify the parser pool in your `loadXml` call:

```
val doc = loadXml(
  source = new FileReader("data/example.xml"),
  parsers = XIncludeSAXParserFactoryPool.parsers
)
```

Note though that if you have relative URIs in your `include` `href`s and you want them evaluated relative to the location of the document (rather than the current directory), you'll need to be sure that the `InputSource` gets the system ID. Here's one way to do this:

```
import java.io.File
import org.xml.sax.InputSource

loadXml(
  source = new InputSource(new File("data/example.xml").toUri.toString),
  parsers = XIncludeSAXParserFactoryPool.parsers
)
```

All of the above should work in 0.5.0 as well as 0.6.0.

If there are better ways to solve this problem, I'd love to hear them.